# How to 1) remove 2) get the list item labels from a Java String using regex?

Tags: java, regex

How could I 1) remove 2) get the list item labels from a Java String using regex?

For example:

```
1.   text other text ...
2.1. text
(b)  text
 c)  text
     text
ii)  text
(iv) text
```

I am trying to get:

```
1.
2.1.
(b)
c)

ii)
(iv)
```

I am trying to find a regex to be able to get the labels / also another one to delete it.

splitting by space ')' or '.' would not work cause it could also be on other lines

Comment: so you want everything before `SPACE` followed by `some text` to the `EOL` ?

Comment: Is there a label on every line, or can some lines be unlabeled (presumably continuations of the `text` from a previous labeled line)?

Comment: no some of them are missing labels

Answer (score 0):

If we assume '.' and ')' as the only characters the labels can end with then we can have the following regex:`^\w*[.)]`. In java this could be like:

```
str.replaceFirst("^\\w*[.)]","");
```